# VBA (in MS Project) writing data to an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I am working on a MS Project macro to extract some data from our schedules. I am having an issue creating and saving the excel file. The code below seems to work but then pops up

*"Run Time Error '1004': SaveAs method of Workbook class failed".*

This seems to indicate an issue with accessing the file, but the file is created and has the data in it. I'm not sure what "failed", or how to get rid of the error message. The box only lets me debug or end the program. Continue is greyed out. Any thoughts?

```
' Need to add "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library" in Tools...References
Dim Xl As Excel.Application
Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.worksheet

ResourceFileName = Replace(ActiveProject.FullName, ".mpp", "-Resource.xlsx")
If Dir(ResourceFileName) <> "" Then Kill ResourceFileName

Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set WB = Xl.Workbooks.Add
Set WS1 = Xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
WS1.Name = "ResourceData"

<... do some stuff here ...>

WB.SaveAs FileName:=ResourceFileName
WB.Close
Xl.Quit
Set Xl = Nothing
```

Comment: Have you checked if the value of `ResourceFileName` is what you expect?

Comment: It looks correct, and like I said, the file gets created with the data, it just throws an error.

Comment: You will need to specify the workbook type.  [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

Comment: I added XlFileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault to the SaveAs line. I still get the error.

Comment: Hmm. Is it perhaps a file already exists problem?

Comment: You might get better info if you (temporarily) switch to early binding

Comment: I added this right below the ResourceFileName line - If Dir(ResourceFileName) <> "" Then Kill ResourceFileName. Problem persists. Maybe a filesystem caching issue with the OS? I'll erase the file, and let it sit a few minutes and see if that solves it.

Comment: Also, the code is working. It gets the values, creates the file, puts the values in the file. Everything works fine, it just pops that error box.

Comment: Another possibility: check Task Manager for instances of Excel.  You aren't closing the wb or quitting Excel, so the file may still be "in use"

Comment: I added 'Dim Xl As Object' at the top, and I get "Application-defined or object-defined error". Also Excel pops up with the properly formed worksheet, but the Title is 'Book1' and the file is not present where it should be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249709/discussion-between-chris-neilsen-and-mister-rose).

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to have come from OneDrive trying to sync the excel file. I think the sync process was hanging up the state of the file, so even though it was deleted on the computer, it was not deleted yet remotely, and the system still had the file name "open". Once I moved to a non-OneDrive location, the above code worked repeatedly.